# How can I make a Drawable array of ONE image?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, gridview, android-drawable

I have this image:

```
 int lettersIcon[] ={
    R.drawable.ico_x
};
```

And I want to repeat this on a matrix/gridview (NxM) times.

I don't know much about Android.

Comment: or give me a link if this question is repeated...

Comment: In gridview adapter there will be getCount() method. there you return the number you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.picassoapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   GridView gridView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gridView = findViewById(R.id.grid);
        GridAdapter adapter= new GridAdapter(R.drawable.cute_cat);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <GridView
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

GridAdapter:

```
    package com.example.picassoapp;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int images;
    public GridAdapter(int images) {
        this.images= images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return images;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_adapter, null);
        ImageView imageView= view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(images);
        return view;
    }
}
```

grid_adapter.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```